# jdbc driver to connect oracle from python

Tags: python, jdbc

Do you know of any library to use a jdbc url to connect oracle using python?
i tried using pyodbc but its slow while retrieving million records.
note: pyodbc uses odbc connections

Thanks in advance
sreeni

Comment: jdbc url to access db from python.  its specify question

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/)?

> The JayDeBeApi module allows you to connect from Python code to
>   databases using Java JDBC. It provides a Python DB-API v2.0 to that
>   database.

Comment: thanks. just checked it has python3 support as well

Answer (score -2):

*cx_Oracle* Python Database Drivers is one option

Refer the following Link

- https://dzone.com/articles/oracle-database-python-driver-cx-oracle-now-on-git

My work for you

Comment: sorry it does not help. wanted a jdbc url connectivity to oracle from python. The link does not speak about jdbc at all

Comment: @SriniSydney Why do you want to use JDBC from python? That is rather backwards, as JDBC is for applications in the JVM, and using it from python (except maybe Jython) would have a lot of overhead compared to a Python specific driver.

Comment: There are codebases in multiple languages (R, Python, Java) which use to connect to our datalake. Hence using jdbc url as the common middleware protocol for db connectivity